# Import vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need import component with data into vue.js app.

I can component registration and I used this code.

**Correct Code:**

```
  export default {
    name: 'hello',
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
      }
    },
    components: {
      'test': {
        template: '<div>msg: {{message}}</div>',
        props: {
          message: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But how can I Local Registration with data?

**NOT correct:**

```
import Test from './components/Test.vue';

export default {
    name: 'hello',
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
      }
    },
    components: {
      'test': {
        template: Test,
        props: {
          message: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You want a nested component to have its own `data` property? Just put `data` along with `props`, `template` etc.

Comment: Basic question first, are you using Webpack to preprocess your app? Because I can't see anything immediately incorrect about your component.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
import Test from './components/Test.vue';

export default {
    name: 'hello',
    data () {
      return {
        msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
      }
    },
    components: {
      Test
    }
  }
```

And if you want to pass props

```
<template>
<Test :message=msg></Test>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `props` in component code (components/xxx.vue) and resolved it.